# Is there some good Twisted cheat sheets or reference cards?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm recently started to learn Twisted framework and now looking for some cheat sheets/reference cards with basic Twisted stuff. Such as deferreds, callbacks, reactor, protocols, factories, transports, so on.

At the moment found nothing neither on http://refcardz.dzone.com/ nor on http://www.cheat-sheets.org/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This page is full of stuff: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Documentation.  How can one of these not be a suitable "cheat-sheet"?  Can you list each one and how it fails to match your definition of "cheat-sheet"?

Comment: As wp says, Cheatsheets is a concise set of notes used for quick reference; wiki documentation can't be used as a cheatsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I know of is [Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Twisted](http://mumak.net/stuff/twisted-intro.html)

It's not really a "cheat-sheet", but it is a concise introduction to most of the basic concepts.

Comment: it's updated http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html